# "Weighted average" for medians

Tags: mean, median, weighted

I have data that includes ~20 groups with descriptive stats of median, count, and mean for each of the groups. I know that the means are heavily skewed, and I don't have access to the underlying data to remove outliers.

What I want to do essentially is find a weighted average of the medians, so I can visualize the relative importance of each of the categories, while using only median and count.

What I had done is just take the median * count for each category, then divide by the sum product of median * count for all categories to get a percentage weighting.

Is this a "legit" statistical approach? Is there a more direct, or at least easier to explain approach to this.

The second step would be to try to apply the weights to the median of all the data points. So if the median is lets say 8, could I apply the weighting from the above approach to this figure of 8. e.g. group 1 has a 20% weight. I can somewhat say then that group 1's "share" of the grand total median is 1.6. Is this feasible?

I understand I am really just trying to find a weighted average, but I can't use means and I only have the summary data points, not raw data.

Comment: You might get better answers if you can give descriptive statistics for three or four of your 20 groups, to give some idea of sample sizes, degree of skewness, etc. What is your purpose in trying to get the overall median of the combined groups? Do you have any idea from what family of distributions the 20 groups were randomly sampled? // My Answer below shows some of the fundamental difficulties by looking at three groups of equal sample sizes, so that weighting is not an issue.

Answer (score 2):

Consider three samples (groups) `a`,`b`, and `c`, each of size $n=20$ from exponential
distributions with different rates $\lambda_i,$ where means are
reciprocal rates $\mu_i = 1/\lambda_i$

We can find the mean of the grand sample of all sixty observations by averaging the the three group means (weighted average if sample sizes differed), but it is not possible
to find the median of the grand sample from the medians of the three groups.

Three groups of equal size:

```
set.seed(113)
a = rexp(20, 1/2); length(a); mean(a); median(a)
[1] 20
[1] 1.825926
[1] 1.322669

b = rexp(20, 1/10); length(b); mean(b); median(b)
[1] 20
[1] 9.402898
[1] 4.726509

c = rexp(20, 1/50); length(c); mean(c); median(c)
[1] 20
[1] 43.62316
[1] 38.04221
```

Grand sample `x` (possible because all 60 observations are available).

```
x = c(a,b,c); length(x); mean(x); median(x)
[1] 60
[1] 18.284    # mean of grand sample
[1] 4.40221   $ median of grand sample
```

Finding mean of `x` from group means:

```
mean(c(mean(a),mean(b),mean(c)))
[1] 18.284    # matches mean of grand sample above
```

Failure to find median of `x` from group medians:

```
mean(c(median(a),median(b),median(c)))
[1] 14.69713  # not equal to 4.40221
median(c(median(a),median(b),median(c)))
[1] 4.726509  # median of (b); not equal to 4.40221
```

Of the failed attempts, the median of group medians comes closest
to the median of the grand sample. If samples were of different
sizes you might try to find the 'median' group by some criterion
and use its median. [Here it seems obvious to use `b` because it has 20 observations "above" and 20 observations "below" (ignoring some overlaps).]

```
boxplot(a,b,c,x, col=c("red","green3", "skyblue2", "grey"), 
        horizontal=T, varwidth=T)
```

[image]

*Notes:* (1) If you know the distributional form of the populations from which
groups were sampled, you might be able to simulate each group. That is
feasible here because the three exponential rates can be estimated as
the reciprocals of group sample means. So `y` below might be a reasonable
'reconstruction' of the grand sample `x` and the sample median of `y` might
be near to the sample median of `x`:

```
y = c(rexp(20, 1/mean(a)), rexp(20, 1/mean(b)), rexp(20, 1/mean(c)))
median(y)
[1] 5.08311   # roughly the same as median of `x`: 4.402
boxplot(x,y, horizontal=T)
```

[image]

This is hardly a high-precision procedure, its values are usually
in the interval $(2.4, 8.5),$ which does include 4.4.

```
 set.seed(1234)
 r1 = 1/mean(a); r2 = 1/mean(b);  r3 = 1/mean(c)
 h = replicate(10^5, median( c(rexp(20,r1), rexp(20,r2), rexp(20,r3)) ))
 quantile(h, c(.025,.975))
    2.5%    97.5% 
3.406778 8.586979
```

(2) If group sample sizes are very large, the sample means do not differ much from group to group, and the ratio between sample means and sample variances is nearly the same in each group, then you may be able to approximate
the sample median as a multiple of the weighted average.

Example: For exponential data
the population median $\eta = \ln(2)\mu$ and this relationship between medians and means is approximately true for large samples.

```
set.seed(120)
w = rexp(10000, 1/5)
mean(w);  median(w);  mean(w)*log(2)
[1] 5.026372
[1] 3.515211
[1] 3.484016
```